# If $a>0$ and $ab>0$, then $b>0$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I've been trying to find a proof for that, I'm not sure if it's an axiom or if it's a property derived from an axiom. More precisely:

> Let $a,b$ be real numbers then the following properties must follow:
> if $a>0$ and $ab>0$ then it must follow that $b>0$. Similarly, if
> $a<0$ and $ab<0$ then $b>0$.

Is there a way to prove that using only field properties for real numbers?

Edit for context:
I was originally trying to prove that $a<b$ and $c>0$, then $ac<bc$. I did that by proceeding by contradiction, assuming $ac-bc<0$ then $c(a-b) <0$ and since $c>0$ why can we say that $a-b<0$? Is that an axiom? I was just proving inequality properties for addition and this one was next.

Comment: Can you obtain a contradiction if $b=0$ or $b < 0$?

Comment: Clearly for $b=0$ there's a contradiction. For $b<0$ I can't seem to find one.

Comment: If $b < 0$ and $a > 0$ then what is the sign of $ab$?

Comment: They have opposite signs but I feel like the statement is precisely that: proving that if $ab<0$ then $a$ and $b$ have different signs.

Comment: What properties/axioms are you starting with, regarding the ordering of real numbers?

Comment: Inequality properties for addition and that $a<b$ implies $-a>-b$

Comment: Assume $a<0$, from the assumption $ab>0$ you have $-ab=(-a)b<0$ but both $-a, b$ are positive then so is their product.

Answer (score 1):

By way of contradiction, if $b \leq 0$, then since $a > 0$ we have $ab \leq 0$. The proof for the latter is similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'll left another route:

Step 1: Show that $a^{-1}>0$

Proof: Clearly $a^{-1}\neq 0$ so let's suppose that $a^{-1}<0$. Then $-a^{-1}>0$ and since positive numbers are closed under multiplication, $$a\cdot (-a^{-1}) > 0 \implies -(a\cdot a^{-1}) >0 \implies -1 >0$$ which is a contradiction. Thus, $a>0 \iff a^{-1}>0$

Step 2: Thanks to step 1, $a>0 \iff a^{-1}>0$. Again, positive numbers are closed under multiplication so $a^{-1}\cdot ab > 0$. But now we can use associativity: $$a^{-1}\cdot ab = (a^{-1}\cdot a)b >0 \implies b> 0$$

Comment: By "positive numbers are closed under multiplication" you mean $a>0$, $c>0$ implies $ac>0$. Is that an axiom?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be postulated as an axiom by itself, but I'm very sure that it can be stated as a consequence of ordering axioms. Wikipedia state it as a property https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number